# Magento upsell_products raises error "must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection"

Tags: php, magento

Putting this line to view.phtml ...

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

... raises this error:

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::_addProductAttributesAndPrices() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection, instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Product_Collection given, called in D:\active\***\src\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Upsell.php on line 65 and defined  in D:\active\***\src\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php on line 355

#0 D:\active\***\src\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php(355): mageCoreErrorHandler(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', 'D:\active\***...', 355, Array)
#1 D:\active\***\src\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Upsell.php(65): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Product_Collection))
#2 D:\active\***\src\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Upsell.php(94): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell->_prepareData()
#3 D:\active\***\src\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell->_beforeToHtml()
#4 D:\active\***\src\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#5 D:\active\***\src\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('upsell_products', true)
#6 D:\active\***\src\app\design\frontend\default\***\template\catalog\product\view.phtml(163): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('upsell_products')
```

I found only one [forum topic](http://magento-forum.ru/topic/1360/) and it says that there is magento 1.6 core with not compatible modules.

Can you help me to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue that came from the extension "Market Ready Germany 2.1.3". It came from an incompatible core overwrite that broke the product view pages.

#### How to fix it for Magento from 1.5.+

**1. Copy current core file**

from

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php
```

to

```
\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php
```

Backup the existing file in local (rename it).

**2. Compare both files**

Open the old local file and search for this method:

```
public function getPriceHtml
```

There should be two sections with commentary around them:

```
//begin: symmetrics code
...
//end: symmetrics code
```

- Copy the first symmetrics section to the methods beginning, and copy the second section to the return value.
- Delete the content of var/cache/* and open a product view page and it will not log any more errors.

That should fix it.

Comment: I just deleted \app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is one quick solution: edit file 
\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php

and change

> protected function _addProductAttributesAndPrices(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection $collection)

to

> protected function _addProductAttributesAndPrices(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Product_Collection $collection)

But this is not the best solution.